# How to monitor Kafka broker using jmxtrans?

Tags: jmx, apache-kafka, jmxtrans

Kafka 0.8.1.1 (kafka_2.8.0-0.8.1.1.tgz)

I am using jmxtrans to do JMX monitoring of a Kafka instance (which is running in docker).  Unfortunately, kafka metrics are not being returned.

I have tried a few things to debug this and know that kafka is running correctly (I can produce/consume messages successfully) have concluded that jmxtrans does return JMX metrics (for example, java.lang:type=Memory, attribute=HeapMemoryUsage returns correct data) so the general kafka and JMX capability seems to be working.  Also, I can access the metrics when I use jconsole -- the metrics seem to be captured with data in all relevant fields.

When I try jmxtrans using the following configuration, unfortunately, I do not get any information back (no data at all in fact).  I believe the metrics are supposed to be captured based upon the kafka documentation ("kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics", attribute="MessagesInPerSec")

The following is the jmxtrans configuration that I used:

```
{
    "servers" : [ {
        "port" : "9999",
        "host" : "10.0.1.201",
        "queries" : [ {
            "outputWriters" : [ {
                "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.StdOutWriter",
                "settings" : {
                 }
             } ],
             "obj" : "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics",
             "attr" : [ "MessagesInPerSec" ]
         } ],
         "numQueryThreads" : 2
     } ]
}
```

I am not sure why data is not returned.  Maybe I setup an invalid jmxtrans configuration or perhaps I am specifying the metric improperly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I have now resolved the question.  For completeness, below is how I resolved the problem.

It appears that I specified the "obj" value incorrectly.

The CORRECT obj value (an example) is as follows:

```
"obj": "\"kafka.server\":type=\"BrokerTopicMetrics\",name \"AllTopicsLogBytesAppendedPerSec\"",
"attr": [ "Count" ]
```

Note that the "obj" value requires additional quotes.  This seems unusual and different than the normal pattern I have seen (no quotes) for other JMX obj values.

JMXTRANS provided valid output after putting the correct (quoted) values in the obj string...

Comment: What Kafka version are you using? I'm using the latest version built from the sources and there were indeed some changes around JMX. You're right that using the `\`s was a solution, but it won't be once you've upgraded.

Comment: I will be upgrading to the next version shortly - do you happen to know when it was fixed (ie.  not requiring quotes)?

Comment: Not exactly, but I was working with the latest version built from the sources, so it's gonna be surely in the next version.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a few days. I have followed the same pattern (except that I needed to place an '='). '"obj":"\"kafka.server\":type=\"ReplicaManager\",name=\"UnderReplicatedPartitions\""'. But I still see nothing being written to the file. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As I could've found out in `./bin/jmxtrans.sh`, by default the stdout/log file is `/dev/null`.

```
LOG_FILE=${LOG_FILE:-"/dev/null"}
```

That's why it's important to set the env var to something you can use to see the output:

```
LOG_FILE=log.txt ./bin/jmxtrans.sh start kafka.json
```

I'm using the following `kafka.json` configuration file:

```
{
  "servers" : [ {
    "port" : "10101",
    "host" : "localhost",
    "queries" : [ {
      "outputWriters" : [ {
        "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.StdOutWriter",
        "settings" : {
        }
      } ],
      "obj" : "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=testowo",
      "attr" : [ "Count" ]
    } ],
    "numQueryThreads" : 2
  } ]
}
```

When you start jmxtrans it will query the broker with JMX on `localhost:10101` about `Count` attribute for `testowo` topic. It *will* print the result out to the file `LOG_FILE` every 60 secs (you can change it using `SECONDS_BETWEEN_RUNS` env var), e.g.

```
LOG_FILE=log.txt SECONDS_BETWEEN_RUNS=5 ./bin/jmxtrans.sh start kafka.json
```

You may want to use other writers of jmxtrans so the output is not intermingled, e.g.

```
{
  "servers" : [ {
    "port" : "10101",
    "host" : "localhost",
    "queries" : [ {
      "outputWriters" : [ {
        "@class" : "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.KeyOutWriter",
        "settings" : {
          "outputFile" : "testowo-counts.txt",
          "maxLogFileSize" : "10MB",
          "maxLogBackupFiles" : 200,
          "delimiter" : "\t",
          "debug" : true
        }
      } ],
      "obj" : "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=testowo",
      "attr" : [ "Count" ]
    } ],
    "numQueryThreads" : 2
  } ]
}
```

And the last but not least, to set the JMX port to a known value use `JMX_PORT` env var when starting a Kafka broker using `./bin/kafka-server-start.sh`, i.e.

```
JMX_PORT=10101 ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Comment: Jacek:  thanks for the detailed response.  I should have mentioned that jmxtrans  successfully provided output when I used obj" : java.lang:type=Memory", "attr" : [ "HeapMemoryUsage", "NonHeapMemoryUsage" ].  Since the JMX output is provided for the aforementioned obj/attr, the JMX port must be setup properly and valid JMX data is available.  By process of elimination, I suspect that the kafka obj value I am trying to use is specified incorrectly.  I will continue to experiment to resolve the error.  Thanks for your help!