# jconsole - MBeans in double quotes

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

Why are the top 3 mbeans in the following picture being shown in double quotes?

[image]

Metrics are shown this way

[image]

Comment: Can you show the full ObjectNames ?

Comment: @Nicholas added the picture

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from these ObjectNames, but I noticed there are 2 Kafka domains that are not quoted so my conjecture is that the JMX developer was trying to deal with key properties that contained JMX disallowed characters (or conditions where one might expect the same). One way is to wholesale replace invalid characters with valid ones. Seems in this case they elected to simply [quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html#quote(java.lang.String)) the whole ObjectName. It is odd (perhaps even buggy ?) that there are 2 separate domains for `"kafka.producer"` and `kafka.producer`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of Kafka you are using... In some versions of Kafka, some of the JMX elements were quoted.  I believe this has been changed in future versions to not require quotes.  Some additional information is available at this post: [How to monitor Kafka broker using jmxtrans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344222/how-to-monitor-kafka-broker-using-jmxtrans)